# How to set a variable from a helper method for inclusion in a SASS SCSS stylesheet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

I have a helper method that retrieves a string that I need to get into a SASS scss stylesheet.  If I call the method in the view it works fine, however it seems that sass is wanting a variable.  It seems as though if I attempt to set a var in the controller, thinking that this would be the correct approach initially, I'm not able to see the var anywhere.

*I initially thought you could simply call a helper method from SASS, but apparently that's not the case?*  If not,

**Could you please provide an example of getting a variable set properly in a sass scss stylesheet that would originally come from a helper method?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rename your SASS file to `foobar.css.scss.erb`. Then include the helper module you need that contains the helper method by placing this line at the top:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include MyHelper } %>
```

Then you can use the helper method with erb

```
.foo {
    color: <%= cool_color %>
}
```