# Ruby on Rails - Using helpers inside css erb file gives undefined method

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, undefined, erb, helper

I have a css.erb file which contains the styling of one of my pages. I have a helper which preformats a URL of a given image based on the location of that image.

When I call the helper function from the view, the output is expected (a string containing the URL for of the image). However, calling it in the css.erb file gives me an `undefined method` error even though I copy and paste the same function into my css file.

It's as if the helper is not included in the css file and is ignored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Helpers are not available by default to templated .css files.  They are intended to help in view construction only.  However, you can try the workaround mentioned [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3116) using an initializer:

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.instance_eval do
  include YourHelperModule
end
```

Alternatively, if you only need this for one or a few files, you can use the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932097/how-to-set-a-variable-from-a-helper-method-for-inclusion-in-a-sass-scss-styleshe), by adding this code to the top of the .css.erb file:

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include YourHelperModule } %>
```

Comment: This works great! Now I have a problem whereby my session variables are not being detected in the Helper (whereas they did if I called the helper from a view). It says, `undefined local variable or method 'session'`. Any idea why?

Comment: Same problem - sessions are only available to the controllers and views, not to assets.  Unfortunately, there's no simple workaround for this.  Assets are designed to be compiled to static files, while session info can't be static by nature.  You're probably better off creating different asset files and using the session to load the proper one for your case.

Comment: The only problem with that is that there would be a lot of repeated style sheets. Thanks anyway, if I find a decent way around this, I'll update this question.

Comment: I'm on this issue too, and I think there is no way to access request or session. Isn't?

Comment: @StefanDunn If I understand the problem correctly, you do not need to repeat CSS. You can just load an additional one, which defines only the differences between the default one.

Comment: @AlbertCatalà You are right, there is no way you could access a session. As PinnyM mentioned earlier, the assets are *compiled* once, and then they are just like *static files*. If you would include some session-specific data in an asset, that data would be then shared by all of your visitors.